# How to make two images equal height and keep it on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make two images which are placed in two floated divs equal height. Both images takes 100% of the page width, but their ratio is 60/40% and I want to kept it like that on resize. So again:
2 images, different height, want to make it same height, I do not care about the width (I will hide it), and ratio stays the same on resize.

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: `background-size: cover;`?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the images in the CSS as background images and give them a size of `cover`. In the example below I used the `background:` [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

See the example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/ey4h8wjx/).

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.foo, .bar { height: 100%; float: left; }

.foo {
     width: 60%;
     background: url("http://url.com/image.png") no-repeat center top / cover;
} 

.bar { 
    width: 40%;
    background: url("http://url.com/image.png") no-repeat center top / cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Orun! But I need something universal, something that is working even if you set two images with different heights...

Comment: This should work even with two completely different sized images. The image will cover the entire `<div>`. The alternative is that you could use `<img>`'s and stretch the image or try to do `overflow:hidden;` on the parent and have the images full sized, but this will take some tinkering (and end up doing the same thing as `background-size: cover;`, except the image will be referenced the HTML instead of the CSS).